# django rest api permission problem with post and put

Tags: python, reactjs, django, rest, axios

I have a problem with post and put request.
My requests with axios in react:

```
handleSubmit() {
        axios.post('http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/tasks/',{
                headers:{"Authorization":`Token ${this.state.token}`},
                author:this.state.id,
                title:this.state.title,
                desc:this.state.desc,
                done:false,
        })
        .then(
            response =>{console.log(response);}
            )
        .then(
            ()=>{window.location.reload(false);}
        )
    }
```

Everything works fine but when i change AllowAny to IsAuthenticated in code below:

```
REST_FRAMEWORK = {
    'DEFAULT_PERMISSION_CLASSES': [
        'rest_framework.permissions.IsAuthenticated',
    ],
    'DEFAULT_AUTHENTICATION_CLASSES': [
        'rest_framework.authentication.SessionAuthentication',
        'rest_framework.authentication.TokenAuthentication',
    ]
}
```

i'm getting an error like this

```
POST http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/tasks/ 403 (Forbidden)
dispatchXhrRequest @ xhr.js:210
xhrAdapter @ xhr.js:15
dispatchRequest @ dispatchRequest.js:58
request @ Axios.js:108
Axios.<computed> @ Axios.js:140
wrap @ bind.js:9
handleSubmit @ TaskCreate.js:41
onClick @ TaskCreate.js:73
callCallback @ react-dom.development.js:3945
invokeGuardedCallbackDev @ react-dom.development.js:3994
invokeGuardedCallback @ react-dom.development.js:4056
invokeGuardedCallbackAndCatchFirstError @ react-dom.development.js:4070
executeDispatch @ react-dom.development.js:8243
processDispatchQueueItemsInOrder @ react-dom.development.js:8275
processDispatchQueue @ react-dom.development.js:8288
dispatchEventsForPlugins @ react-dom.development.js:8299
(anonymous) @ react-dom.development.js:8508
batchedEventUpdates$1 @ react-dom.development.js:22396
batchedEventUpdates @ react-dom.development.js:3745
dispatchEventForPluginEventSystem @ react-dom.development.js:8507
attemptToDispatchEvent @ react-dom.development.js:6005
dispatchEvent @ react-dom.development.js:5924
unstable_runWithPriority @ scheduler.development.js:468
runWithPriority$1 @ react-dom.development.js:11276
discreteUpdates$1 @ react-dom.development.js:22413
discreteUpdates @ react-dom.development.js:3756
dispatchDiscreteEvent @ react-dom.development.js:5889
createError.js:16 Uncaught (in promise) Error: Request failed with status code 403
    at createError (createError.js:16)
    at settle (settle.js:17)
    at XMLHttpRequest.onloadend (xhr.js:66)
```

In addition to that, get requests work correctly even if i change to isAuthenticated.

```
const getTasks = () =>{ //this works fine 
        axios.get("http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/tasks/"+`user/${id}/` 
        ,{headers:{"Authorization":`Token ${props.token}`}})
        .then(
            response => {
                setTasks(response.data);
            }
        )
    }
```

I have been searching for answer 4 days now and i can't get any explanations of that problem.
Also there put request:

```
const doneTask = (t_id,title,desc) => {
        axios.put("http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/tasks/"+`${t_id}/`,{
            headers:{"Authorization":`Token ${props.token}`,"Content-Type":'application/json'},
                author: 1,
                title: title,
                desc: desc,
                done: true
            
        }
            )
        .then((response)=>{
            console.log(response);
        }).catch((error)=>{console.log(error)})
        .then(
            ()=>{window.location.reload(false);}
        )
        
    }
```

And example of API view in django rest:

```
class TaskList(generics.ListCreateAPIView):
    queryset = Task.objects.all()
    serializer_class = TaskSerializer
```

Do i need to send sessionid in header? I removed csrf from django by commenting this out, since i have token verification.

Comment: Can you post Django PUT method code

Comment: Can you also show your an example of your API view please

Comment: I think It is csrf related issue, You can use ```@csrf_exempt``` in django above API method.

Comment: I've tried that and the error stay the same @ShakeelAfridi